# In select2, the values always is a empty string

Tags: django, vue.js, jquery-select2

I have a Python/Django project where I'm trying to add 'select2' to facilitate user search from a list of banks:

```
class BuyerNaturalPersonBankAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
select_bank = MajorBankList(
    label='Banco',
    required=False,
    )

class Meta:
    model = BuyerBankAccount
    fields = (
        'name',
        'cpf',
        'cnpj',
        'select_bank',
        'bank',
        'bank_code',
        'agency',
        'account',
        'account_type',
    )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['bank'].required = False
    self.fields['bank_code'].required = False
    self.fields['bank'].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            'v-model': 'bank',
            ':disabled': 'isBankDisabled',
        }
    )
    self.fields['bank_code'].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            'v-model': 'bank_code',
            ':disabled': 'isBankDisabled',
        }
    )
    self.fields['select_bank'].widget = forms.Select(
        choices=self.fields['select_bank'].choices,
        attrs={
            'v-model': 'selectedBank',
            '@change': 'onBankChange',
            'data-select2-enabled': True,
        }
    )
```

In my base.html, i have added the select2:

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        data: {
            street: '',
            district: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            country: '',
            cpf: '',
            name: '',
            mother_name: '',
            father_name: '',
            nationality: '',
            selectedBank: '',
            bank: '',
            bank_code: '',
            bankAccountOwnerName: '',
            bankAccountCPF: '',
            birth_date: '',
            public_person: false,
            isLoading: false,
            isPostalCodeFound: true,
            isCPFFound: true,
            display_form_address: false,
            display_form_bank: false,
            hasError: '{{ error }}',
        },
        beforeMount: function () {
            this.bank = this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-bank').value
            this.bank_code= this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-bank_code').value
            this.postal_code = this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-postal_code').value
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('[data-select2-enabled]').select2({
                    closeOnSelect: true,
                    theme: "bootstrap"
                });
            });
            </script>
```

In the HTML template, I perform these check:

```
            computed: {
            isBankDisabled: function() {
                return this.selectedBank ==! '';
            }
        },
```

If I change the check to: return this.selectedBank ==='';, the value always becomes true, meaning it is always an empty value. I believe the select2 field is always passing the value as blank. How can I check so that when it has the placeholder, the field is false, and when the user selects any value, it becomes true?